# Is it possible to test specific Spring REST endpoint security and avoid bootstrapping database connection?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have a couple of Spring tests that call a secured controller endpoints. Our goal is to assure that absence of particular user roles will result into HTTP 403 status.
Our issue is that execution of those tests also bootstraps DB connection which we don't actually need.
I've already tried countless number of all kind of annotations and manual configurations to avoid initialization of DB connection but so far without luck. Can you please share example how to do that?
We use Spring Boot 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `@WebMvcTest`, take a look [at the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.spring-mvc-tests). In summary, using `@WebMvcTest` will only bootstrap the Spring MVC components and avoid loading other application's layers. This annotation also automatically configures Spring Security for you, therefore you can test authentication/authorization rules.

Example:

```java
@WebMvcTest(UserVehicleController.class)
class MyControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserVehicleService userVehicleService;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")
    void testAdminSuccess() throws Exception {
        given(this.userVehicleService.getVehicleDetails("sboot"))
            .willReturn(new VehicleDetails("Honda", "Civic"));
        this.mvc.perform(get("/sboot/vehicle").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("Honda Civic"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = "USER")
    void testUserForbidden() throws Exception {
        this.mvc.perform(get("/sboot/vehicle").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
            .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcus but unfortunately when I do this the DB connection still gets initialized "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting..." :(

Comment: Please edit your question and share more about how you are creating the connection with the db, the dependencies, and every piece of code that might be related